# Why is my 2.4ghz router dropping speed when WAN is from 2.4Ghz bridge on distant channel?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, wifi-configuration, interference, dual-band

Follow along here, because this isn't a standard setup.

I have a 2.4Ghz bridge connecting two "sites".  It is on channel 13 and there is no other device detected up there in my area.  The link is as solid as I could hope for and I can get 55/14 Dn/Up all day long with an Internet speed test (which is the same I can pull on my wired PC).

So that's great.  Where I have a problem is when I put a router on the receiving end and and connect a client to it on 2.4Ghz.  The router can be on any channel (I tried every channel from 1 to 13) using 20 or 40 width... it doesn't matter.  The net result is my speed tests drop to a max of around 30/14, usually hitting about half (27/7).

I've ruled out a lot of things.  First off, I connected the router directly to the main WAN router and the same clients then pull 55/14 as expected - that rules out the router and router/client connection being too poor to handle the speed.  Second, I connect a client to the router by 5Ghz with the bridge in use and I still pull 55/14 - that proves that the problem isn't with the bridge or the combination of the two.  I think that means it HAS to be 2.4 interference... but why if I'm on such dissimilar channels (say 1 vs 13)?

Or is it something else?

Comment: If the router is physically close to the bridge receiver,  try moving it farther away. Or, maybe reduce power on the router (an option on some models). Try a different (better?) cable for the interconnect. Try plugging the two devices into different outlets.

Comment: OK, I moved the router and it is now about 10 feet away horizontally and 5 feet lower.  Should this be sufficient?  It was the furthest convenient location to try but I could go further.  It made no difference.  I realize I misread your suggestion and I tried reducing the bridge's power, not the router's... so I'll try that next.  It has dd-wrt so I'm sure I can.  Through this process I have tried different cables and the one I've used most is a brand new CAT6 that links at 1000M.  They are on different outlets.

Comment: I think you made a good case for RF interference being the problem. Yes, you should reduce the power on the router, not the bridge. Does the bridge have a directional antenna? Can you add one? Keep the router well off axis of the bridge antenna direction.

Comment: The bridge has directional on the "remote" end (where the problem is) and omni on the "base" side.  The "base" side does have an external antenna connector so I could add a directional if we think that would make a difference.  I kind of enjoy it having omni because i can also pick up the signal in the exterior spaces... but that is by no means critical.  I reduced the power on the router and it did not resolve the issue.  All it did was make the speeds even slower (once I dropped it down to about 15dB).  I'm convinced it is RF because there have been infrequent brief periods where I get 55.

Comment: I guess we don't know which device, router or bridge, is throttling your speed. Can you get them each to display signal-to-noise ratio and see which one drops in the bad config?